# php unlink file renovated

Tags: php, download, unlink

I want to delete with php (unlink function) file which is out of webroot. my web root is in

```
C:\server\webroot\project\... in webroot I have folder named project and in there I have .php files.
```

whats about files directory. it is situated C:\server\mp3_files...

Also I've created in httpd.conf Alias("mp3") of mp3_files directory

---

I am writing this script in C:\server\webroot\project\test.php

script is like so =>

```
function delete($filename){
if (unlink("/mp3/" . $filename)){
    echo "Deleted";
} else {
    echo "No";
}
 }
delete("file.txt");
```

this script gives me in php-errors => **PHP-WARNING No such file or directory**

also I have in (test.php) html form this =>

```
<a href="/mp3/file.txt">Download</a>
```

And this works (It opens this file.txt)

So I'm wondered why can't delete with marked function "delete($filename)" ?

Comment: PHP does not know about Apache aliased folders. You must use absolute or relative paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"/mp3/" . $filename is an absolute filepath, not relative to the webserver root, so it's assuming that you have an mp3 directory under your filesystem root when you should be looking under /server/mp3

**EDIT**

And is it /server/mp3 or /server/mp3_files

your post seems to contradict your code

Comment: Nothing is contradict here, just it is right that file functions can't see aliases , with mp3_files it is working but with Alias(mp3) it doesn't

Comment: Apache aliases are recognised by Apache, but not by PHP... filesystem functions work from the filesystem, not from apache

Comment: but with <a href='/mp3/file.txt'>File</a> I can see this file => so it is going out that in this situation alias works , I can not get it well

Comment: The URL reference in <a href='/mp3/file.txt'>File</a> is being processed by Apache, not by PHP or the filesystem, so the Alias is valid here

Comment: and also I have one question too. Is this <a href='/mp3/file.txt'>File</a> valid download link ? I am asking because browsers opens it (don't download) if the file is .mp3 file firefox and safari download but chrome opens and opera doesn't do anything (lol). So I am interested that is this <a href=''></a> valid for downloading file ?

Comment: Thye browser will try to access the file, how it works then is dependent on the filetype and the browser

Answer (score 2):

File function in PHP go from the file system root.

You should write:

```
function delete($filename){
if (unlink("C:\\server\\mp3_files\\" . $filename)){
    echo "Deleted";
} else {
    echo "No";
}
 }
delete("file.txt");
```

Comment: I have tried this also , but result is same => PHP-WARNING No such file or directory

Comment: I am not used with Windows Server, but I am guessing you should not be using forward slashes but you double backslashes instead.

Comment: Yes, the file functions don't know about aliases.

Comment: That is going so :). And also I have one question about how to make download links. I am writing <a href='<?php $path ?>'>file</a> and some browser starts download some not and also if the file is .txt file it is opening (not downloading) and why is it so ?

Answer (score 1):

To make sure the internal PHP file path cache gets the correct information, reset with it with [`clearstatcache()`](http://php.net/manual/function.clearstatcache.php) before and after the unlink. Normally the path cache is reseted after every PHP function which is related to file manipulation. Reseting the cache is required if you remove files with `shell_exec('rm file.txt')` or similar.

See http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.realpath-cache-size and http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.realpath-cache-ttl